# Why is this sentence wrong?

Tags: verbs, translation, past-tense

In a translation exercise, I was asked to translate

> She went to see the doctor

in Italian. I answered *sei andata dal dottore*; however, it was marked wrong. The correct answer appears to be *lei andava dal dottore*: why is it so?

Comment: Alright, I know what is wrong. I use the wrong essere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Sei andata dal dottore" means "you went to see the doctor" because "sei" is second person singular. The translation of the sentence should be "è andata dal dottore". 
The sentence "lei andava dal dottore" means "she was going to see the doctor."

Comment: grrazie!it came to my mind later. but thank you anyway

Comment: "lei andava dal dottore" can also be translated with "she went to the doctor", it depends on the context.

Comment: @karoshi: That's true! It's difficult to give a correct translation without a context.

Comment: *Andò dal dottore* would be a better choice of tense, according to Italian grammar. However *passato remoto* is almost never used in certain parts of Italy.

Comment: @egreg:  Of course! I thought by the kind of question that the OP is someone who is starting to learn Italian, so that he or she probably hasn't studied the "passato remoto" yet.

Comment: ...italian language stackexchange website, that's fantastic!